# Using CSS and/or Bootstrap to float a Navbar link to the right

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to float my last 2 link items in my top navbar but the bootstrap class: 'Float-right' isnt working and neither is selecting with css. I've wrapped my text in a div and tried to float it using CSS since the bootstrap way didn't work.

Here is the code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>SoundOff Signal</title>
  </head>

  <div class="container">
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">EMERGENCY <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">AMBER</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">GOVERNMENT</a>
          </li>
          <!-- This is where I want to intiate my link float-->

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">FIND A DEALER</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">DEALER PORTER</a>
          </li>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

```css
.navbar {
    background-color: black;
}

.card-body {
    text-align: center;
}

body {
    background-color: black;
}

nav {
    background-color: #1E1F22;
}


.float {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have your body tag as a child of a div? That's invalid HTML

Comment: I didnt add all the code in the snippet. I have since added the rest

Comment: Same issue still exists

Comment: There is still have a body tag within a div. Also, the body tag is never closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add w-100 class on your ul to get 100% width for your navbar and ml-auto instead of you float class to push this div to right

```
 <ul class="navbar-nav w-100">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">EMERGENCY <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">AMBER</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">GOVERNMENT</a>
      </li>
      <!-- This is where I want to intiate my link float-->
      <div class="ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">FIND A DEALER</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">DEALER PORTER</a>
      </li>
      </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Live [example](https://jsfiddle.net/p6mo7es2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary">
<a class="navbar-brand abs" href="#">Your Logo/ Name</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsingNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="collapsingNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
             <a class="nav-link" href="#">EMERGENCY <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">AMBER</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">GOVERNMENT</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">FIND A DEALER</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">DEALER PORTER</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: you sould explain your code and not only post the code